# History.js first load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, history.js

I'm using History.js with jQuery.

My page is a search engine.

The form is submitted via $.ajax() and the result is loaded in div#results with pagination.
A click on next page's link is handled by $.ajax too.

Each result is a link to another page.

When I first load my form, I want div#results to be empty. But when I click on result's link then the back button, I want the div#results with the same results.

```
$('.link_page').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var page = $(this).data('page');
    $.ajax({
      url: '/search',
      method: 'POST',
      data: {
        create_date : $('#create_date').val(),
        page        : page
      } 
    }).done(function( html ) {
      $( "#results" ).html( html );
      History.pushState({results: html}, "Search", "/search");
    });
  });

History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function (evt) {
  var state = History.getState();
  $( "#results" ).html( state.data.results );
});

History.Adapter.onDomLoad(function(){
  var state = History.getState();
  History.replaceState({results: state.data.results}, "Search", "/search");
});
```

It works well but if I submit my form then I go to any pages of my site and finally I return to my form, the div#results is still filled with the previous search.